# What does it mean when there is an equals line through an angle?

Tags: geometry, notation, angle

[image: triangle with line through angle]

What does this line through the angle mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of stroke at an angle might be a way to say that angle is the same as some other angle (not shown). It would be analogous to the single and double strokes through the segments HE and HY. If there were another segment elsewhere with two strokes it would be the same length as HE.

To know whether this is what the stroke on the angle means we would need to see much more context.